# Аналог "умного фильтра" для Битрикс в версии "Стандарт"?

Tags: php, битрикс

Делаю сайт на 1С-Битрикс, версия "Стандарт"**(важно!)**.

Есть инфоблок содержащий элементы с "ФИО", "Должность", "Возраст" и "Стаж работы".
Выше него должен быть элемент, куда вводим данные для фильтрации инфоблока по стажу, должности, возрасту.

Поскольку я новичок, не знал с какой стороны подступиться к данному заданию.
Посмотрел несколько видео на ютубе, большинство реализует подобный функционал через ["Умный фильтр"](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/components/content/catalog/smart_filter.php), но он недоступен в моей версии Битрикса(стандарт).

Вопрос как реализовать данный функционал, учитывая ограничения по версии?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Одна из идей умного фильтра в том, что он формирует массив фильтрации для компонента catalog.section. Если вы выводите список при помощи компонента news.list, то вам нужно будет реализовать собственный компонент, который так же будет создавать массив для фильтрации и передавать данный массив в параметрах компонента news.list (FILTER_NAME).
Другая идея умного фильтра: значения в фильтре зависят друг от друга, то есть фильтр перестраивается при изменении какого-либо параметра в фильтре. Придётся этот функционал реализовывать как-то самим, например, при помощи CIBlockElement::GetPropertyValues

Comment: Купить себе отдельное решение с умным фильтром. Когда битрикс еще не доделал свой пользовались им - http://marketplace.1c-bitrix.ru/solutions/kombox.filter/